# Block all methods except GET to root url of my application

Tags: angular, angular15, angular-guards

I am experiencing an issue where any call to my root URL, http://example.com, is returning a 200 response, but I would like to restrict this behavior to only GET methods for security purposes. I have tried multiple approaches such as backend middleware, frontend interceptors and guards, and AWS API Gateway, but I have not found a solution yet.

I have ruled out the backend approach because I do not have a root project - it is a modular .NET Core API where the Angular frontend retrieves information from each module to build the component. I have also ruled out AWS WAF (Web Application Firewall) due to cost issues, but I am open to using it if it is the only viable option.

If you require any additional information or code samples that I have used, please let me know. Thank you.